# Gap between consecutive Dirichlet eigenvalues

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ is a domain with a Lipschitz boundary and let $\{\lambda_k\}_{k=0}^n$ be the eigenvalues for the Laplacian operator on $\Omega$, that is to say
$$ -\Delta \phi_k = \lambda_k \,\phi_k \quad \text{on $\Omega$} \quad \text{and $\phi_k \in H^1_0(\Omega)$.} $$

Is it true that given any $N>0$, there exists some $k \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$\lambda_{k+1}-\lambda_k > N$$

This claim can be readily verified for squares but I wonder if it is true more generally.

Comment: How do you see it for squares?

Comment: Its enough to find long strings of consecutive integers that can not be written as sums of two squares. This can be done using chineese remainder theorem.

Comment: Does this not come out of [Weyl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_law) ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling: ah, of course. Thanks.

Comment: How do you see this? To me the Polya conjecture is about lower bounds and doesn't produce counter examples, at least not right away.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Not clear also for me. Do you mean that there are counterexamples if Polya's conjecture fails?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: Indeed, I was too quick. A closer look at the link (see eq. (a7) there) shows that the Polya conjecture implies that $\lambda_k\ge Ck$, where $C$ is the constant from Weyl's law, which says that $\lambda_k=(C+o(1))k$. That gives gaps $\le o(1)k$, so isn't quite enough for the present question.